# Four cards are drawn from a pack of 52 cards. What is the chance that no two cards are of equal value

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

**Four cards are drawn from a pack of 52 cards. What is the chance that no two cards are of equal value? Each belongs to a different suit?**
My try--
Total probability =$^{52}C_4$
In the pack of 52 cards there are 4 aces, 4 1s and so on. So, there will be 13 groups of 4 cards containing same value.
$\therefore$ Probability that no two cards are of equal value =$\frac{^{13}C_4\times ^4C_1}{^{52}C_4}=\frac{44}{4165}$
But given answer is=$\frac{2816}{4165}$
I think I did it wrong, please help me. I also couldn't solve the 2nd problem.

Comment: The probability you calculated of $\binom{13}{4}\times\binom{4}{1}/\binom{52}{4}$ is the probability that every card is of different rank but every card is *of the same suit*.  If you wanted all cards to be different rank *and* different suit, that should have been a $4!$, not a $\binom{4}{1}$.  If you didn't care about suits being repeated then that should have been a $4^4$... or if you absolutely insist... $\binom{4}{1}\times\binom{4}{1}\times\binom{4}{1}\times\binom{4}{1}$ (*but this just makes it harder to read and is annoying*)

Comment: As for the question of asking the probability that all four cards are of different suit but you don't care about repeated ranks, that is covered by what I linked this as a duplicate of.

Comment: @JMoravitz are you saying it will be $\frac{^{13}C_4\times 4!}{^{52}C_4}$? But, it doesn't match the answer.

Comment: All different ranks *and* all different suits: $\binom{13}{4}\cdot 4!/\binom{52}{4}$.  All different ranks, all the same suit: $\binom{13}{4}\cdot 4/\binom{52}{4}$.  All different ranks, no restriction on suits: $\binom{13}{4}4^4/\binom{52}{4}$.  Read what I wrote more carefully.  Continuing: All the same rank: $13/\binom{52}{4}$.  No restriction on ranks all different suits: $13^4/\binom{52}{4}$, and so on...  There are many similarly sounding questions with slightly altered conditions.  Do not confuse one question for another.